# Error not switching Form in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have created many Forms in Visual Studio using c#. After create them I want to test those Forms one by one. But after I tested the first Form, I want to test the second Form. But it not working, it still running in the first Form no matter how much I try to switch Form in (Program.cs) it not work and still running in The first form. Any solutions please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7F63.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, error messages, etc. Post text as text, formatted appropriately. We can't copy text from a picture to search or test. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to properly ask a question.

Comment: If you want to use a different startup form for your app, do that in the project properties. Don't edit that part of the code manually without a good reason. Usually, if you want open other forms, you do that from the code of the startup form. As it stands, the code you have should display the second form only after you close the first. If that's what's happening then the code is working exactly as should be expected.

Comment: Did you comment the original form? Or whether the UserList form has the function of displaying form1. If these are all OK, please use the Visual Studio installation tool to repair Visual Studio or upgrade Visual Studio 2022 to the latest version

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `Application.Run()` to run your form. To run the user list form, you must delete or comment the `Application.Run(new Form5);` that you wrote on the top line, like below:

[image: Program.cs]

There is another solution where you have to make your form into an object and then display it with the command below:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.ShowDialog();
```

[image: Form2 UI]

[image: Form2 code behind]